# Django channels username sender

Tags: django, django-channels

I am new to Django channels , i followed the documentation tutorial and i made a Django chat room , so far i can send and recieve messages , but the probleme here the sender is unknown , i tried to send the username but  its not working , i get the username printed in the server but in the front i get the actual login username?? i am confused  ?

consumer.py :

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        print(self.user.username)

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username' : str(self.user.username),
        }))
```

room.html :

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">username :
     <a  id="username" href="">{{ user.get_username }}</a>
     <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="75"/><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
</div>

</body>
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        console.log(e.data)

        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += ( message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is happening vs what should be happening? It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: the message sent by any user in the chat room is anonymous, i want something like username1 : hello , username2 : hi

Comment: I don't think your including the username when you are sending the message to all other channels in the group. Under your group send function try adding 'username': self.user.username and then add in your javascript parse 'username' to display it in the same way that you parse the message itself. If you do that, whenever a user sends a message his/her username will be included in the group send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user connects, he gets a separate instance of the `ChatConsumer` and you set the `self.user`. If he receives a message from another channel, the `self.user` does not change, it is still the one you set for him. So to show the username of the sender, you have to send it along with the message like this:

```
    ...
    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': self.user.username
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        print(username)

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username' : username,
        }))
```

It is important to note that separate instances of ChatConsumer run the methods `receive` and `chat_message`, hence the `self.user` in those methods are different. While the `receive` method is executed in the sender's channel, the `chat_message` method is executed in the channels of the receivers which will also include the sender in this case, since he is in the same group as the receivers.
For example, to see if the message you received was sent by you, you could do something like this in the `chat_message` method:

```
if event['username'] == self.user.username:
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I was working on this same problem and tested this solution which worked for me. I attach the logged-in username to the message.

```
# Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
        
    username = self.scope["user"].username # store logged-in user from WebSocket scope
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    message = (username + ': ' + message) # add to message here
    
    # Send message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message,
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
    
    username = self.scope["user"].username
    message = event['message']
    
    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message,
        "username": username,
    }))
```